# Checkboxes below checked checkbox can't be checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Hello I am having problems on fixing this. I have 4 checkboxes wherein only 1 checkbox should be checked at a time. Meaning that if the second box is currently checked and I ticked the first box, then the second box's check should be removed.

My problem is that when i tick a checkbox, I can't check other checkboxes below it anymore. I need to uncheck the box first before it could be functional again.

Here's my javascript

```
var a = $('.8kfth').val();
        $(':checkbox').on('click', this, function(){
            if ($('.8kfirstchk').prop('checked')==true && $('.8kfth').val()=="one")
            {
                $('.8ksecondchk, .8kthirdchk, .8kfourthchk').prop('checked', false);
                $('.ft-identifier').html('').append('8-K with 425');
            }
            else if ($('.8ksecondchk').prop('checked')==true && $('.8kfth').val()=="one")
            {
                $('.8kfirstchk, .8kthirdchk, .8kfourthchk').prop('checked', false);
                $('.ft-identifier').html('').append('8-K with DEFA14A or DFAN14A');
            }
            else if ($('.8kthirdchk').prop('checked')==true && $('.8kfth').val()=="one")
            {
                $('.8kfirstchk, .8ksecondchk, .8kfourthchk').prop('checked', false);
                $('.ft-identifier').html('').append('8-K with SC TO-C');
            }
            else if ($('.8kfourthchk').prop('checked')==true && $('.8kfth').val()=="one")
            {
                $('.8kfirstchk, .8ksecondchk, .8kthirdchk').prop('checked', false);
                $('.ft-identifier').html('').append('8-K with SC TO-C');
            }
        });
```

And here's the html

```
<P align=center><select class="8kfth"><option></option><option><value="one">one</option><option value="two">two</option></select></P>

<TABLE style="LINE-HEIGHT: 13pt; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0>

<TR vAlign=bottom>
    <TD NOWRAP WIDTH="1%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT size=2 face="Times New Roman"><input type="checkbox" class="8kfirstchk">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="99%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT face="Times New Roman" size=2>425</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR>
    <TD NOWRAP WIDTH="1%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT size=2 face="Times New Roman">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="99%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"></TD></TR>
<TR vAlign=bottom>
    <TD NOWRAP WIDTH="1%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT size=2 face="Times New Roman"><input type="checkbox" class="8ksecondchk"></FONT></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="99%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT face="Times New Roman" size=2>PANDA</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR>
    <TD NOWRAP WIDTH="1%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT size=2 face="Times New Roman">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="99%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"></TD></TR>
<TR vAlign=bottom>
    <TD NOWRAP WIDTH="1%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT size=2 face="Times New Roman"><input type="checkbox"  class="8kthirdchk"></FONT></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="99%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT face="Times New Roman" size=2>SCIENCE TO SCIENCE</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR>
    <TD NOWRAP WIDTH="1%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT size=2 face="Times New Roman">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="99%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"></TD></TR>
<TR vAlign=bottom>
    <TD NOWRAP WIDTH="1%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT size=2 face="Times New Roman"><input type="checkbox"  class="8kfourthchk"></FONT></TD>
    <TD WIDTH="99%" STYLE="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle"><FONT face="Times New Roman" size=2>SCIENCE TO SCIENCE</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>
```

here is a fiddle if it would help https://jsfiddle.net/yguch1yb/
(Note that you need to select one in the drop down to arrive to my problem)

Comment: Why do you not use radio buttons?

Comment: I'm trying to create a template and I wanted it to be very similar as to what was in the source. And I don't know if I remember this correctly but with using radio buttons, you would need to have the form tag for it to behave correctly.

Comment: I hope you;re not using a table for layout; that's what CSS is for. And the `<font>` tag is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to create checkbox groups that you can specify with a number. So this one code will apply to multiple groups as you define them. Also this will simply verify that the only value in the given group is the last value you have selected.

```js
$('input[data-checkGroup]').on('click',function(){
  let item = this;
  let group = $(this).attr('data-checkGroup');
  let checked = $('[data-checkGroup="'+group+'"]:checked');
  $.each(checked,function(k,v){
    if(v !== item) v.checked = false;
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" data-checkGroup="1"> Value 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-checkGroup="1"> Value 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-checkGroup="1"> Value 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-checkGroup="1"> Value 4

<br/>

<span class="log"></span>
```

Comment: Magic! I don't understand some parts like the k and the v thing but it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Selim The k and v stand for Key and Value. the query `$('[data-checkGroup="'+group+'"]:checked');` grabs a list of every checked box that matches the `data-checkGroup` id and puts them in an array. The `$.each()` function loops through the array and sets ever element that is not the element that you just clicked to equal false. Let me know if i can explain anything further!